# Get previous site url in a Single Page Application using javascript

Tags: javascript, navigation, single-page-application

I'm working on a vue single page application.

**Situation**: I have a page which displays `1..*` results (Page A), if there is only 1 result available, then this result is automatically selected; meaning the user is redirected to the items detail page (Page B).

```
[Page A] <-> [Page B]
```

**Problem**: if the user is on Page B and navigates back then the 'auto-select'-clause is triggered again which results in a redirect again to Page B. This means you cannot navigate back once you've entered Page B - this is unacceptable.

**Thoughts**: The best solution I can think of is to add a check to the auto-select clause which matches the origin (where the user came from, e.g. Page B) to the desired destination (where to user is redirected to, e.g. also Page B), and if they do match, do not trigger the redirect. The problem is that I have no way of knowing where the user was before.

I tried to use `document.referrer` but this isn't suitable for a single page application.

I tried to work with vue-router properties, but none of which brought me any futher.

The only other solution I can think of is to store each navigation in a cookie (or similar) to match against, but since this is quite a rare case I try to avoid having too much of an overhead.

Any idea? Is there something similar like `document.referrer` but for single page applications? Or is there a way to extract information from the `history`?

Comment: [The `History` interface allows manipulation of the browser session history.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History)

Comment: @AjAX. yes I'm aware of that, but I wasn't able to extract the raw url from the history. manipulating the 'flow' isn't the problem, the problem is missing information

Comment: I guess it is `history.go(-2)`.

Comment: @AjAX. no, that is not the same

Comment: Your site sounds like made static by Javascript. You can log all the pages visited in an object. From there you can make the appropiate `redirects`.

Answer (score -1):

When result is only 1, then PageA will redirected to PageB ,if in this case , let the route like "/PageB?only=1".
in pageB, if the query's only is 1, then when you click the back button,redirected the page that you want to back.
I am not sure it is the best~ but it should work。

Comment: I also thought of this but figured there must be a better way